# How would you run code once per second on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Heroku supports background workers and cron (daily, hourly) but I'm looking for a way to run code once a second.

Let's say I have a game backend on Heroku and want to timeout some player action after some time.

How would  you solve for this?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider running an Amazon EC2 instance that does nothing but run this task once a second. US East would be geographically local to the Heroku instances, and you could also run other non-Heroku supported services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try rufus scheduler:

Install the gem

```
 gem install rufus-scheduler
```

Make sure you include the gem in bundler or however you are including it.

Then you need to create a file called `task_scheduler.rb` and stick this in you `initializers` directory.

```
 require 'rufus/scheduler'
 scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

 scheduler.every '1s' do

      puts "Test!"      
      #do something here

 end
```

If you have any trouble you can see this blog post:

http://intridea.com/2009/2/13/dead-simple-task-scheduling-in-rails?blog=company

Comment: A library like [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) is also useful in this scenario, though it will require a separate dyno to run.

Answer (score 0):

Some Javascript polling might be an alternative to a Heroku worker that runs some code every second. Something that performs an AJAX call after a given period of time.

Running a Heroku worker to run some code every second doesn't seem hugely cost effective or efficient.

Off the top of my head, perhaps:

```
var codeToRun = function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: '/test',
          success: function(){
            alert('Code was run.');
          }
    )};
}

timer = window.setInterval(codeToRun,1000);
```